# WPF, app looses ability to create or manipulate GUI objects

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

i need some help with WPF

I'm getting started with WPF and wanted to make a simple snake game with the following classes:

```
GameBoard : Window
{
  private Game game;

  public GameBoard(){ this.game = new Game(this); }

  public Rectangle rectangleFactory(int x, int y)
  { 
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.Width = 10;
    rect.Height = 10;
    GameArea.Children.Add(rect); /// My Canvas is called GameArea
    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 10 * x);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, 10 * y);
    return rect;
}

  public void rectangleBin(Rectangle)
  {
    GameArea.Children.Remove(rect);
  }
}

Thing{
  private GameBoard Board;
  private System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect;
  private int[] coordinaters;

  public Thing(GameBoard board, int[] coordinates)
  { 
    this.Board = board; 
    Draw();
  }

  public Draw(){ rect = Board.rectangleFactory(coordinates);}
  public Dispose(){ Board.rectangleBin(rect)}
}

SnakeSegment : Thing 
{
  SnakeSegment next;
  public SnakeSegment(GameBoard board, int[] coordinates) : base(board, coordinates) { } 
}

Apple : Thing()
{
  public Apple(GameBoard board, int[] coordinates) : base(board, coordinates) { }

  public void newApple()
  {
    Dispose();
    getNewCoordinate();
    Draw();
  }
}

Game
{
  private GameBoard Board;
  private Apple apple;
  Private Snake snake;
  private static System.timers.timer timer

  public Game(GameBoard board)
  {
    this.Board = board;
    this.apple = new Apple(board, int start_coordinates);
    this.snake = new snake(this);
    this.timer = new Timer(100);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(update_game);
  }

  public void update_game(object o, ElapsedEventArgs s){ snake.move_forward(); }
}


Snake
{
  private SnakeSegmet Head;
  Private SnakeSegment Tail
  private GameBoard Board;

  public Snake(Game game)
  {
    this.Board = game.Board;
    this.Head = new SnakeSegment(Board, start_cooridantse)
    this.Tail = Head;
  }

  private void AddSegment()
  {
    Head.Next = new SnakeSegment(Board, newCoordinates);
    Head = Head.Next;
  }
}
```

There is of course more but i left it out in the interest of readability.

When i start the game it draws the game area and adds an apple and an initial rectangle for the snake, so far so good

But then i update the game and things go south
my next call to SnakeSegment constructor in `Head.Next = new SnakeSegment()`
ends in rectangleFactory when calling `new Rectangle()`

the program doesn't crash, but it topples the current stack and nothing more is executed untinl the timer raises an other event

ive tried to troubleshoot and reroute the flow a bit and if i instead call Apple::newApple() the same thing happens when i get to `GameArea.Children.Remove(rect);`

Im completely new to WPF and this really gives me a headache, if anybody could explain why it happens id be very grateful.

Regards, Tobias

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI Elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.** Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore Not the greatest advice frankly. There will always be need for UI code. Custom behaviors, dynamic animations, custom controls.

Comment: @Gusdor wrong. Beginners in WPF **must** understand that WPF is NOT winforms, nor any other crappy dinosaur half-baked deprecated useless wannabe UI framework. See Sheridan's answer. Once the inital mindshift is made, you will know what belongs in code behind and what belongs in the VMs and what belongs in XAML.

Comment: @HighCore use as much bold text as you like, it doesn't stop _"Don't create or manipulate UI Elements in procedural code in WPF."_ from being a very strong and harmful statement. For any serious work, you will have to. Microsoft's implementations are not good enough alone. Patterns are a means, not an end. MVVM + Template will not solve every problem - consider `Adorner`s.

Comment: @Gusdor my comment is targetted to entry level developers, that will NOT do "serious work", and yes, this particular problem in this question can be resolved by using WPF's DataBinding and templating capabilities, as opposed to using a crappy procedural winforms-like code behind approach.

Comment: @HighCore So at what point do you start giving the good advice? 2 years in to a career? 6 months? Why not just give it immediately? MVVM _can_ solve this problem, but the statement you made was _never do X Y and Z in WPF_. If he ramps his object count right up, writing `Visual` level code may be better. He might not need to right now but never say never. Additionally, lets put a lid on that language shall we?

Comment: @gusdor procedural winforms still sucks, no matter what. and my point still stands. Period. Goodbye. BTW, read my comment again. I said clearly: `once the initial mindshift is made, you will know what belongs in code behind and what belongs in the VMs and what belongs in XAML`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write your program like that, use WinForms. If you want to use WPF, you'll need to pretty much start again from scratch. WPF is a data-centric language... we manipulate data objects, not UI objects.

Using WPF, you'd need to think about your game objects as a collection of data objects. The board would then be the UI container control that you data bind your collection to. You would then define what each object should look like in a `DataTemplate` in the XAML. After binding the location properties of the data objects to the location properties of the UI objects you could then move the objects in the UI by changing the location properties of the data objects from code.

Having said all that, I think that you'll find that WPF is not a good Framework for making games. Its main strengths are its data binding capabilities and rich UI possibilities, but it's not very efficient. You'll need a good graphics card to get the most out of it.

Comment: Thanks Sherridan, you are no doubt correct. I choose to do it in WPF simply because i wanted to use it a little and get a feel for it. So its not totally bad that im forced to actually learn a bit in the process.

Comment: Just a suggestion, my dear colleague, the word "language" is not the best choice to describe WPF, which is not a language, but a Framework. While it is obvious that you know that, it might not be evident for the reader, and it's important to always make clear the differences between languages and frameworks.

Comment: Worth mentioning that XNA is depreciated.